# How to add windows (desktop) to android studio devices

Tags: android-studio, flutter, desktop-application, android-virtual-device, flutter-desktop

Iam creating a flutter desktop app ,how to add windows (desktop) device to android studio virtual devices as in the image below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The device list is filtered to what platforms you can build the currently open project for, so for Windows to show up in your device list you need:

- [Desktop support enabled](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Desktop-shells#tooling) in the Flutter tool.
- [A `windows` runner](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Desktop-shells#create) set up for the project you want to build.

Comment: I ran it with command `flutter run -d windows` throwgh the terminal ,but it didnt appear in the devices list !